# How to retrive list of data from room database that has same email address

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm saving an object of user contact and in object, i have made email address primary key now I want to retrieve list of data that has similar email address, how can I do that right now only an object is retrieving rather than list of contact that has same email address, the query is:

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM userContact WHERE email = :email")
public List<UserContact> getUserContactWith(String email);
```

Comment: If an email is primary key this query will return one user contact or non

Comment: what should I do? also is query right?

Comment: if you need similar emails than use LIKE operator, if different contacts can have the same email than don't use primary key

Comment: could you answer?

Answer (score 0):

If email address is the primary key, you cannot have more than 1 record having a particular email address.

Comment: By default, as soon as you try to save the data to the table, either it will throw an exception saying Primary Key constraint violated or it will overwrite the data. In both the cases, you cannot have two records with same email address.